# list of change in the registry keys from lync to skype for business 2016

Tags: registry, skype-for-business

Want to know the list of registry keys that have been changed from lync 2013 to Skype for business  2016.

Some time i m not able to make a call from my outlook but i was working fine on office 2013.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn´t be easy to give you a fully set of registry files, as it might be that Microsoft change that with every hotfix. So the best way would be to create two sets of registry files on your side and then compare them together as for example written [here](https://superuser.com/questions/79566/whats-the-easiest-and-fastest-way-to-compare-2-registry-files).